# Grunt not compiling sass

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs

I am working with an old project which uses grunt as a build tool, I had to install newer version of node-sass since to be able to rebuild node-sass. Now when I am trying to make changes in sass files, and run grunt I don't that anything has compiled. This is my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'compressed',
          sourceComments: 'none'
        },
        files: {
          'css/app.css': 'scss/app.scss'
        }
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'expanded',
          sourceComments: 'map',
          sourceMap: 'app.css.map'
        },
        files: {
          'css/app.css': 'scss/app.scss'
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      grunt: { files: ['Gruntfile.js'] },

      sass: {
        files: 'assets/scss/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass:dev']
      },

      css: {
        files: ['assets/css/*.css'],
        tasks: [],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass:dist']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dev', 'watch']);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your path is wrong in your SASS task.
Replace:

`'scss/app.scss'`

with

`'assets/scss/app.scss'`